# Validate for File naming scheme

Tags: validation, scheme, directory, naming

I have a file that drops into a folder location. I'm looking for a file named like this.

ID _Data_Tape_CCYYMMDD_hhmmss.txt

How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a regular expression? in Racket, this will match the given file name:

```
(define name "42_Data_Tape_11220331_234532.txt")

(regexp-match #px"\\d+_Data_Tape_\\d{8}_\\d{6}.txt" name)
=> '("42_Data_Tape_11220331_234532.txt")

(regexp-match #px"\\d+_Data_Tape_\\d{8}_\\d{6}.txt" "something-else")
=> #f
```

To list all the files in a directory use [`directory-list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._directory-list%29%29) or an equivalent procedure in your interpreter, then match their names against the above regular expression - and there, you found the files with the expected name.

Comment: like this ^\d _Data_Tape_\\d{8}_\\d{6}.txt